# Finding the maximum product of a path in binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I need some help to come up with an algorithm to calculate maximum product of the values along any path from leaf to root of a binary tree. So far I have:

```
int max_path_prod_rec(Tree* t, int max_so_far, int path_prod) {
    if (is_leaf(t)) 
        return t->value;   

    int left = max_path_prod_rec(t->left, max_so_far, path_prod);
    int right = max_path_prod_rec(t->right, max_so_far, path_prod);

    if (left > right) 
        return left * t->value;
    else 
        return right * t->value;
}

int max_path_prod(Tree* t) {
    require("path product only defined for non-empty trees", t != NULL);
    return max_path_prod_rec(t, INT_MIN, 1);
}
```

The problem is this function doesn't work when there are 2 negative numbers in a row, like 10 * (-3) * (-6). How can I improve upon this?

Edit: examples:

```
    //   10
    //  2   5
    // 1 -3 4 -6
    t = node(node(leaf(1), 2, leaf(-3)), 10, node(leaf(4), 5, leaf(-6)));
    printf("%i\n", max_path_prod(t));
```

Will return `10 * 5 * 4 == 200`. But

```
    //   10
    //  2   -5
    // 1 -3 4 -6
    t = node(node(leaf(1), 2, leaf(-3)), 10, node(leaf(4), -5, leaf(-6)));
    printf("%i\n", max_path_prod(t));
```

Returns `10 * 2 * 1 == 20` instead of `10 * (-5) * (-6) == 300`

Comment: Immediately I note that there is no update to `max_so_far` or to `path_prod`. What is the point of these parameters?

Comment: @Chris Hi, the parameters were given in advance and my attempts so far do not use them. There were no clear explains given but imo `max_so_far` is the maximum value updated after each depth level and `path_prod` is the current path production.

Comment: You shouw show a [mcve]

Comment: Language note: the result of multiplying two or more numbers is their *product*, not their production.  I have edited the question title and text to reflect this.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have added 2 examples for this, thank you.

Comment: Multiply `t->value` first, compare after?

Comment: As an ancillary issue, your code seems to assume that the tree is complete.  That is, that every non-leaf node has two child nodes.  That's not usually a safe assumption.

Comment: @JohnBollinger True, I also have the problem when one of the child node is NULL, but I wanted to concentrate on solving the algorithm first.

Comment: @HoangPhuongTran please ready closely what a [MCVE] is. Roughly it's something we can copy/past/compile and run without hassle, not code snippets we need to stitch together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of a path can only be known when all its nodes have been visited and *no partial path is decisive*. So you have to traverse the entire tree. Arrange a standard tree traversal, but keep a trace of the products along the partial paths, and on every node update the maximum so far.

(Your solution abandons some paths prematurely.)

---

A simple solution:

```
if (is_leaf(t))
    return t->value;
else
    return max(t->value * product(t->left), t->value * product(t->right));
```

Comment: Unless you hit 0?

Comment: @Neil: well observed ! (Of course, 0 could be the maximum, but there is no need to visit the descendants of a 0).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, if the tree has only one child, it will not be a leaf, and will call the next iteration with `NULL` in one of the children.

Comment: @LuisColorado: this has been discussed by the OP in his comments. There is an implicit assumption that it does not occur.

Comment: anyway, it will be more robust (because it admits it) to return 1 in case the pointer value is `NULL`, and don't consider if the node is a leaf node or not.

Comment: @LuisColorado: your comment(s) are irrelevant to the question, don't insist.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that when processing a subtree, you need to account for sign changes that will be applied when the subtree result is incorporated into the result for the overall tree.  If the overall result is going to be negative then you want to minimize the absolute value; otherwise, you want to maximize it.  But you *can* know that, and in fact, you can do even better.

I am not going to write a solution to this exercise for you, but you have a reasonable foundation, and I will try to set you on the right path.  Consider your function signature:

> ```
> int max_path_prod_rec(Tree* t, int max_so_far, int path_prod)
> ```

Now look at your implementation of that function.  Are you really using `max_so_far` and `path_prod` in the ways that their names imply? What would happen if you updated your function to pass correct values of those parameters when it recurses?  How could it use one or both of them to help it achieve the objective?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should write a simpler routine (there's no need to pass down anything to the subtrees, as we are building the product from the leaves to the root)

```
int max_path_prod_rec(Tree* t)
{
    if (t == NULL) return 1;
    int left  = max_path_prod_rec(t->left);
    int right = max_path_prod_rec(t->right);
    return (left > right ? left : right) * t->value; 
}
```

In your code:

```
int max_path_prod_rec(Tree* t, int max_so_far, int path_prod) {
    if (is_leaf(t)) /* you should have posted this function */
        return t->value;
```

Until here you are correct (assuming you will never pass a `NULL` reference to the `t` parameter)...

```
    int left  = max_path_prod_rec(t->left,  max_so_far, path_prod);
    int right = max_path_prod_rec(t->right, max_so_far, path_prod);
```

but here you are assuming that the node, if it's not a leaf node, will have both children attached, and that can be not the case!  You should do those, checking if the children do exist only.

```
    if (left > right) 
        return left  * t->value;
    else 
        return right * t->value;
}
```

In case you have done:

```
int max_path_prod_rec(Tree* t, int max_so_far, int path_prod) {
    if (t == NULL) 
        return 1; /* you add always an extra factor of 1, don't hurt */

    int left  = max_path_prod_rec(t->left,  max_so_far, path_prod);
    int right = max_path_prod_rec(t->right, max_so_far, path_prod);

    if (left > right) 
        return left * t->value;
    else 
        return right * t->value;
}
```

then your code would be protected, and your code would result (for a leaf node) with both children being `1`, and the returned value being `t->value * 1 * 1` ==> `t->value`

If you want to compare absolute values, just do:

```
int max_path_prod_rec(Tree* t)
{
    if (t == NULL) return 1;
    int left  = t->value * max_path_prod_rec(t->left);
    int right = t->value * max_path_prod_rec(t->right);
    return abs(left) > abs(right)
              ? left
              : right; 
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for explaining with this much detail. Does the part `? left : right` do the same thing as `return left else return right`?

Comment: Yes, but try it!!!  You'll see it happening :)